# Laravel much better of using if

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

so most of time i do this

```
@if(!empty($variable)
  @if($variable == "yes")
      do something here
  @endif
@endif
```

well as you can see it really not a beautiful way, maybe (i really hope there is) a much simpler way to just detect if the variable is exist and not throwing error when it is not exist beside that...?

it making my code so crowded and if by anychance i forgot to add those will got beautiful error (well i design a eye cathing error page by the way)

```
@if(!empty($variable))
or 
@if(isempty($variable))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the two checks into a single `if` statement:

```
@if (! empty($variable) && $variable == 'yes')
    do something here
@endif
```

Comment: hahaha lol how come i forgot about this... sorry my bad, i also notice that i using it somewhere else just like this...

Answer (score 0):

if you are searching for one line condition, it will work as expected,

```
  {{!empty($variable) ? $variable == 'yes' ? 'do something' : 'do something else' : 'variable is empty'}}
```